# Swift- How to re arrange uicollection view cell by drag and drop

Tags: swift, ios8, uicollectionview

How to implement a functionality like to rearrange the cells in uicollection view by drag and drop.

I searched lot of library's. i found one [LXReorderableCollectionViewFlowLayout](http://www.hideandgo.com/index.php?q=aHR0cHM6Ly9naXRodWIuY29tL2x4Y2lkL0xYUmVvcmRlcmFibGVDb2xsZWN0aW9uVmlld0Zsb3dMYXlvdXQ%3D&hl=3ed). But is in Objective-c. Is there any library like this in swift. please suggest me.

Comment: You can always use Objective-C's libraries in Swift.

Comment: Please give some idea how to integrate objectve-c in Swift

Comment: Please have a look http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24002369/how-to-call-objective-c-code-from-swift[http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24002369/how-to-call-objective-c-code-from-swift]